# JUnit 4.x : why is @Before never executed?

Tags: java, junit

When I create an and run unit-test, (in Eclipse (Galileo) with JUnit 4.5 or 4.82),
the @Before is never executed (?).

Below is some sample-code. I would expect the output to be :

```
  initialize  
  testGetFour
```

But it is just :

```
  testGetFour
```

@BeforeClass and @AfterClass are never executed either.
Can someone tell me how come ?

```
public class SomeClass
{
  public static int getFour()
  {
    return 4;
  }  
}

//---

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class TestSomeClass extends TestCase
{
  @Before 
  public void initialize() // This method will never execute (?!).
  {
    System.err.println("initialize"); 
  }

  @Test
  public void testGetFour()
  {
    System.err.println("testGetFour");        
    assertEquals(4, SomeClass.getFour());
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Because you're extending `TestCase`. This is a JUnit3 class, and so Eclipse treats it as such. JUnit 4 does not require the test class to extend anything.

Remove that, it should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

You should not extend from TestCase (JUnit 3 way of using JUnit) and it will work.